# Typo3 Extbase How can I get all Objects with a relation = x?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I want to use Extbase on my Project. But I don't get this query to Work:

```
SELECT
    tx_domain_model_A.*,
    tx_domain_model_B.*
FROM
    tx_domain_model_A LEFT JOIN tx_domain_model_B ON (tx_domain_model_B.uid IN (tx_domain_model_A.b_I_D))
WHERE
    tx_domain_model_B.von >= ?
ORDER BY tx_domain_model_B.von
```

The result should like this:

```
A.uid   A.b_I_D B.uid   B.von
1       5,8,3   5       abc
1       5,8,3   8       def
1       5,8,3   3       ghi
2       1,2     1       123
2       1,2     2       456
3       1       1       123
```

I use:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->matching($query->greaterThanOrEqual('bID.von',date('U')));
```

But then, all Child Objects are empty. I think this comes from:
http://fossies.org/dox/typo3_src-6.2.9/Typo3DbQueryParser_8php_source.html

```
function addUnionStatement ...
...

    // TODO check if there is another solution for this
    785         $sql['keywords']['distinct'] = 'DISTINCT';
```

So I do it with a `$query->statement(...)` but this don't work too.

I want to get all Objects from Table A which have `A.B_I_D.von` bigger than today. Table B (= `A.B_I_D`) is an n:1 relation (`A=n:B=1`). How can I get an Object from A more than one time? And can use it in Fluid?

I use Typo3 6.2

Comment: Which error do you get with `$query->statement(...)`? I think this way should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok first of all extbase queries will always give you full objects as a result. that is why you need to use `statement` to achive your goal. The second trick to get the result as you want is that you need to set to receive result as a array. It is needed beacause extbase is trying to map your statement to object of model related with repository

you can change the type of return data using `setReturnRawQueryResult`: you can read more about it here http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html